# What are good ways to manage .props files in modules?

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio

I have a fairly large number of .props files, in a simple project the structure looks like:

```
lib
app
props <- .props files go here
```

However for more complicated projects:

```
lib
app
props <- .props files go here
modules/module1/props <- .props files also go here!
modules/module1/lib
```

Where modules are used between different projects.

The problem is that

1. many .props files end up duplicated, for example boost.props, opencv.props and so on... and manual effort is needed to ensure the identical .props files are ... identical
2. sometimes, lib/lib1 has to be moved to modules/module1/lib, and then the .props files need to be manually removed and re-added

Are there better ways of handling this?

Comment: vcpkg or conan might let you get rid of your props files completely

Comment: If you want VS to automatically complete these operations, I am sorry to tell you that VS does not have this function at present.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT I do not need it to be automatic, but I am not sure where the .props files should go with regard to project structure